# Scheme: sequential execution

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I need to do something basically like this:

```
(define test
  (λ (ls1 ls2)
    (cond
      ((empty? ls2) null)
      (else
       (append ls1 (car ls2)) (test ls1 (cdr ls2))) (displayln ls1))))
```

The issue is the else-clause and the function that follows it.  I need both clauses of the else-clause to execute and then I need the last function to execute but I can't get the syntax right.

I need (test '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6)) to result in displaying '(1 2 3 4 5 6) and it has to use the recursive call.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what this procedure should be doing. Are you sure it's supposed to be printing something, or is it just supposed to return `ls1` and `ls2` appended to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you desperately want to solve this recursively, and you don't care about the return value, use

```
(define (test l1 l2)
  (if (null? l2)
    (displayln l1)
    (test (append l1 (list (car l2))) (cdr l2))))
```

(This is very inefficient btw: O(*n* × *m*) memory allocations.)

Answer (score 2):

There is several problem there. First you make an append on a list and an atom (not a list)... at least if `(car l2)` is not a list. Second you probably think that `(append l1 (list (car l2))` modifies `l1`. But this is not the case. The result is a new list.

To sequence your operation you can do as larsmans have said. But you can also write the following

```
(define (test l1 l2)
  (if (null? l2)
      (displayln l1)
      (let ((l1-follow-by-car-l2 (append l1 (list (car l2)))))
        (test l1-follow-by-car-l2 (cdr l2)) ))
```

This has exactly the same behavior.